# Find $a$,$b$, and $c$ in a given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A question I'm trying to figure out is this:

Find the values of $a$,$b$, and $c$ such that the system on linear equations has a)exactly one solution, b) an infinite number of solutions, and c) no solutions.

$x+5y+z=0$

$x+6y-z=0$

$2x+ay+bz=c$

I put this in a matrix and made it as close to row-echelon form as possible.

$\begin{matrix}
  1 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 2a+b-22 & c
 \end{matrix}$

At this point, we know that ($2a+b-22$)z = c

How do I find the values of $a$,$b$, and $c$ from here?

Comment: what if 2a +b -22 =0?

Comment: Hint: no solutions $\iff$ system is incosistent. For example $2a+b-22=0$, $c\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of 'we know' you should write that the last line represents the equality
$(2a+b-22)z=c$.

So, just answer the questions.

a) We get exactly one solution if $2a+b-22\ \ne\ 0$.

b) We get infinite number of solutions if $2a+b-22\ =\ 0\ =\ c$. (Then $z$ can be anything in the (row-reduced form of the) solution.)

c) We get no solution if $2a+b-22\ =\ 0\ $ but $\ c\ne 0$.

Comment: Oh ok, I guess it had to do with more of the semantics of the question than actually knowing how to do it. I was thrown off because it says "values of a,b and c" so I was looking for a definitive answer. Thanks. This helped.